# Parsing and creating objects from text file

Tags: javascript

So i got a task to use fetch method to take text file from one url and after that i need to "*After reading the data from the file, it is necessary to parse them and create Student objects based on them. Parsing can be done using the split () method of the String object. It is best to divide the read text by line breaks, specifying "\ n" for the split () method parameter. Through the array obtained from the split () method, it is then necessary to go through and create individual Student objects. In the end, it is necessary to print all the data of the Student objects on the page, so that an effect like the one in the picture is obtained*".... text file looks like this

```
Ebonie Rangel
7175 Yukon Street
(507) 833-3567
Geography
Keenan Ellwood
2 Elm Lane
(894) 831-6482
History
Kailan Smart
795 Harvard Street
(925) 856-5167
Biology
Kaydan Hirst
9 East Lakeview Ave.
(939) 812-6141
Programming
Isabelle Prentice
700 Rock Maple St.
(899) 875-8627
Math
```

and it needs to look like this

```
Name: Ebonie Rangel 

Adress: 7175 Yukon Street 

Phone : (507) 833-3567

Course: Geography

(there is no black space between rows, only between students)

Name: ----

Adress: ----

Phone : -----

Course: -----
```

so far i did this and im stuck :

```
async function getData() {
  let response = await fetch(
    "https://v-dresevic.github.io/Advanced-JavaScript-Programming/data/students.txt"
  );
  let text = await response.text();
```

Comment: Why are you stuck. The instructions tell you what to do. Probably should look up those terms they're using and experiment

Comment: I did use split metod on text, but after i dont i just dont know how create individual student objects

Comment: ok, after you split (`var array = text.split("\n")`) then loop through array with any of the various javascript loops like this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: inside that loop put a console.log(_something_)  to see what the value is. That value can be then used to create the format you're looking for. This takes alot of trial and error - every coder has spent alot of time on errors that eventually become easy to fix. Keep at it

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```js
class Student {
  constructor(name, address, phone, course) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.course = course;
  }

  getInfo() {
    return `<div class="card">
      <h2>Name: ${this.name}</h2>
      <p>Address: ${this.address}</p>
      <p>Phone: ${this.phone}</p>
      <p>Course: ${this.course}</p>
    </div>`;
  }
}

async function getData() {
  const elmStudents = document.getElementById('students');

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://v-dresevic.github.io/Advanced-JavaScript-Programming/data/students.txt',
    );
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      throw new Error('Error reading data');
    }
    const text = await response.text();
    const rows = text.split('\n');

    const studentCards = rows
      .reduce((acc, stud, index) => {
        if (index % 4 === 0) {
          const [name, address, phone, course] = rows.slice(index, index + 4);
          const student = new Student(name, address, phone, course);
          acc.push(student.getInfo());
        }
        return acc;
      }, [])
      .join('')

    elmStudents.innerHTML = studentCards;
  } catch (err) {
    elmStudents.innerHTML = 'Fetch problem: ' + err.message;
  }
}

getData();
```

```html
<div id="students"></div>
```

We use the `reduce` function to iterate through the rows array and generate the student cards. It only creates student objects and generates the HTML once per group of 4 lines.

We join the generated student cards into a single string before setting the `innerHTML` of the students container. This is more efficient than setting the `innerHTML` in a loop, as it minimizes DOM manipulation.

We check `response.status !== 200` to handle errors more accurately.

Comment: Maybe you provide to the OP some more insights regarding the use of the remainder/modulo operator `%`.

Comment: This condition is used within a loop to group lines of student data into chunks of 4 lines each. When index is a multiple of 4, it means I've reached the start of a new group of data for a student. This is why I created a new Student object and generate the HTML for that student's card when the condition is true.

the condition index % 4 === 0 checks whether index is evenly divisible by 4, meaning there is no remainder when index is divided by 4. When index is 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, and so on, the condition index % 4 === 0 evaluates to true, otherwise is false.

Comment: ... of cause I meant providing it as part of your own answer (which you can edit) and not as a separate comment.